# Go to URL with dropdown values I select (url.com/dropdownvalue1+dropdownvalue2+etc)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I do the following? (using a simple html form and javascript or jquery whatever I need)

1) To have dropdown values appended to URL like this:
http://www.url.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=dropdownvalue1+dropdownvalue2

(+ symbol is going to stay there like "dropdownvalue1" + "+" + "dropdownvalue2")

2) To have URLs built with IFs like this:
http://www.url.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=customvar

Where customvar is like IF dropdownvalue1 = abc AND dropdownvalue2 = def THEN URL = customurl

Both 1 and 2 will send me to that URL when I click submit after selecting dropdown values. How can I do this?

I know how to create the selection and go to URL, but I want to have to click Submit to go to URL and not just go right away and also have those values appended.

```
<select id="dropdown">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="google">Google</option>
<option value="bing">Bing</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dropdown").change(function(){
if ( $("#dropdown option:selected").val() == 'google'){
window.location = 'http://google.com';
}
if ( $("#dropdown option:selected").val() == 'bing'){
window.location = 'http://bing.com';
}
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Redirect to a url based on value of a select box

**Add this button to your HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="url()"/>
```

**The button includes an onclick event that runs this javascript function**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function url() {
        var value1 = $("#dropdown").val();
        if ( value1 == 'google'){
            window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
        }
        if ( value1 == 'bing'){
            window.location.href = 'http://bing.com';
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Alter to suit your needs**
This is the line that gets the value from the select box `var value1 = $("#dropdown").val();`
If you want to create more select boxes, just add another variable to retrieve the data.
e.g. `var value2 = $("#dropdown2").val();`
You can also edit the if statements and use the variables in the window.location redirects.

```
if (value1 == 'google' && value2 == "something"){
    window.location.href = 'http:/google.com?value1='+value1+'&value2='+value2;
}
```

---

## A Simpler Method

Use the select box values to alter a single URL.

```
function url() {
    var value1 = $("#dropdown").val();
    window.location.href = 'http://'+value1+'.com';
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Can you please take a look at my code? http://paulinhomotos1.hospedagemdesites.ws/scripts/option-dropdown.html

Comment: no jquery library = no variables. Add this line above your javascript `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok. It is there now, but the only thing it does is add a "?" symbol next to URL.

Comment: Remove the <form> tags if you don't need them. Also change your url to this `window.location = 'http://www.paulinhomotos.com.br/catalogsearch/result/?q='+valor1+'&asd='+valor2;` to separate the variables.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be window.location.href?